# JQuery: Unable to upload files with csTransPie

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I just 'migrated' my form from [JQTransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/) to [csTransPie](http://www.pkoretic.net/csTransPie/). Everything was fine until i start to test the file upload. It stoped to work. I notice the diference between both, when the file is selected and comes to the file upload field:

- JQTransform: Full file path, like: C:\folder\file.ext
- csTransPie: Just the file: file.ext

If I disable the csTransPie (commenting the css and js) the upload is ok. Am I missing something? Thanks.

**Edit:** Just tested in Firefox and its working. But in IE8 it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug then.
Have you tried with the latest version?
https://github.com/pkoretic/csDefault/tree/master/csDefault

You should open new issue if problem remains
https://github.com/pkoretic/csDefault/issues/new